# GWT Java email - java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: text/html

Tags: java, email, html-email

I am sending an email with html text and an attachment and getting the error:

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: text/html
```

The code is:

```
public void emailMessage(String emailSubject, String message, String emailaddress, String imagePath) {  
    //Send an email
    try {

        //Send an email
        SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
        email.setHostName("mail.org");
        email.setSmtpPort(25); //No authentication required
        email.setFrom("address.org");
        email.addTo(emailaddress);
        email.setSubject(emailSubject);
        email.setCharset("utf-8");

        // Set the email message text.
        MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messagePart.setText(message, "text/html");

        // Set the email attachment file
        FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(imagePath);

        MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
        attachmentPart.setFileName(fileDataSource.getName());

        // Create Multipart E-Mail.
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);

        email.setContent(multipart);

        //Send the email
        email.send();

    } catch (EmailException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Initially I was sending an email without an attachment which worked. Then I added the multipart for the attachment and the text/html is no longer valid.

Comment: This Jakata Common Email API is an alternative way to solve your problem http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/ , this API also nice for mail handling

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
textPart.setText(text, "utf-8" );
```

or

```
htmlPart.setContent(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8" );
```

Comment: Hi Andrei, The second one works a treat. Now I have an issue with the attachment name. I will raise a new question for that.

Comment: This one worked for me:    MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
             messagePart.setText(html,"UTF-8","html");

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me with java >= 8:

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session)
msg.setContent(content, "text/html")
```

use **setContent** instead **setText**